# GCM has limit of 1000 users. What if we need more?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

If I understand it correctly, Google Cloud Messaging can only send one message to 1000 different phones. But what if we need to increase this number to 1 million, is that possible ?

I tried to go through the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) but I did not find anything.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to send the same message to more than 1000 Registration IDs, you simply split the sending process into groups of 1000 Registration IDs. Each group would be sent in a separate request to GCM server.

Comment: thnxs, 1 more question - is there a website which lists different gcm servers in which ever we like ?

Comment: You should edit your question, GCM doesn't have a 1000 users limit, it has a 1000 simultaneous message sending limit !

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari, _registration_ids: This parameter specifies a list of devices (registration tokens, or IDs) receiving a multicast message. It must contain at least 1 and at most 1000 registration IDs._

Answer (score 0):

FCM has replaced GCM, But still if someone is looking for this answer,
You can check this code from google.

[multicast messages](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/server/gcm/device/MessageSender.java)

Idea is to create a queue
     Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("MulticastMessagesQueue");

and add 1000 device ids to this queue and post a send message.

complete server side code implementation
[server side implementation of google io 2016 app](https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/server)

Comment: both link broken @nkalra0123

Comment: links were from someone else github repo.. looks like he has removed the repo.
And the problem was 4 years old, Now with FCM i think we don't have the same problem anymore.