# Send Notification To All Firebase Cloud Messaging Tokens (Web)

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging

Angular web app (not a native app)
I have my logic working to generate and save FCM tokens.
And I can send a send a message to one token using curl in the terminal.
I have been reviewing MANY tutorials and all I have seen send messages to one token at a time.

Is it possible to send a message to all the tokens you have saved in your Firebase Realtime Database?
Do I need to use (or build) some other tool to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thre is no built-in mechanism in Firebase Cloud Messaging to send a message to "all tokens".

Instead you can call the FCM legacy API to send a message to a collection of up to 1000 tokens at a time. The key is to use the `registration_ids` parameter (instead of the `to` parameter for a single token), as AL explains here: [FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) Send to multiple devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547277/fcm-firebase-cloud-messaging-send-to-multiple-devices) and here: [FCM: Message to multiple registration ids limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375200/fcm-message-to-multiple-registration-ids-limit), and as shown in the [documentation for the legacy API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json).

Comment: It's a tiny app, so I don't think it will hit 1000. This applies to web apps also, not just native apps?

Comment: The API for *sending* messages is the same between all platforms.